# Import Lambda layers locally

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to create a lambda function with a layer, but I'm unable to find a solution to make it work locally. Here's the current directory structure:

```
- projectDir/
  | - lambdas/
  | | - match-puller/
  | | | - scr/...
  | | | - index.ts
  | | | - package.json
  | | | - tsconfig.json
  | - lambda-layers/
  | | - match-puller-layer/
  | | | - scr/...
  | | | - index.ts
  | | | - package.json
  | | | - tsconfig.json
```

In the `match-puller/tsconfig.json` file, I have the following configuration:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "paths": {
      "/opt/nodejs/*": [
        "../../lambda-layers/*"
      ]
    },
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

I'm trying to import my class using the following statement:

```js
import { MatchPullerClass } from "/opt/nodejs/match-puller-layer"
```

For the layer's `tsconfig.json` file, the configuration is as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

And in the layer's `index.ts` file:

```js
import { MatchPullerClass } from './src/index';

export { MatchPullerClass };
```

I don't understand where the error is coming from, but I consistently receive the following error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/match-puller-layer'
Require stack:
- /Users/romain/Developer/projectDir/lambdas/daily-compute/index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/Users/romain/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/romain/Developer/projectDir/lambdas/daily-compute/index.ts:3:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/romain/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/romain/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/romain/Developer/projectDir/lambdas/daily-compute/index.ts' ]
}
source-map-support.js:726
Process exited with code 1
```

However, if I replace `/opt/nodejs/` with `../../lambda-layers/`, it works. I don't understand where the problem might be originating from.

Answer (score 0):

The file structure of Lambda layers are tricky to get right because they need to be exact and are not well documented.

In your case you're missing a `/nodejs` sub-folder to your `match-puller-layer`. This is why you can reference it locally and it fails in execution (or vice-versa).

The reason this is required is that layers support multiple languages for a single layer definition, eg; alongside your `nodejs` you could have a `python` folder:

```
- projectDir/
  | - lambdas/
  | | - match-puller/
  | | | - scr/...
  | | | - index.ts
  | | | - package.json
  | | | - tsconfig.json
  | - lambda-layers/
  | | - match-puller-layer/
  | | | - python/ <-- Python example
  | | | - nodejs/ <-- Required sub-folder for nodejs layers
  | | | | - scr/...
  | | | | - index.ts
  | | | | - package.json
  | | | | - tsconfig.json
```

You'd consequently need to update your `match-puller/tsconfig.json`'s `paths` as well:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "/opt/nodejs/match-puller-layer/*": [
        "../../lambda-layers/match-puller-layer/nodejs/*"
      ]
    },
    // ...
  }
}
```

Although I would actually recommend putting it in the `projectDir`'s `tsconfig.json` rather than having one for every lambda you create.

Take careful note of the local -> lambda path transform, specifically of the `nodejs` positioning: `/.../<layer-name>/nodejs/` -> `/opt/nodejs/<layer-name>/`